# How to output an image with a CNN?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to do depth estimation with CNNs (this is my ultimate goal), but a problem that i found is: I just did image classifications with CNNs, using for example "CIFAR-10", "MNIST", "Cats vs Dogs", etc. To do depth estimation I need to output a new image (the NYUv2 dataset has the labeled images). So, I'll input an image like 256x256x3 and need to output another image with for example 228x228x3.

What I need to do? Can I just do the convolutions for a while and after that decrease the features maps and increase the dimension? Thanks

obs: I'm using Tensorflow 2.0

Comment: It depends on what you need to do but there are several ways to do image-to-image neural networks. You have for example U-nets (https://arxiv.org/abs/1505.04597), Res-nets (https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.03981), Auto-encoders, and much more.
For single-image depth resolution, some people used very complex networks: https://www.cv-foundation.org/openaccess/content_cvpr_2015/papers/Liu_Deep_Convolutional_Neural_2015_CVPR_paper.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use a type of [UNet](https://arxiv.org/abs/1505.04597). This kind of architecture has downsampling layers, followed by up sampling layers to get back to the original spatial dimensions.